# $\cos^2 (\cos^{-1} x)$ $=x^2$ How?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos^2 (\cos^{-1} x)$$
$$=x^2$$

Which trigonometric rule was used here?

Comment: Technically no trigonometric rule was used, the definition of inverse was used i.e $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$, and you simply square the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for a function $f:D_f\to R_f$, where $f$ is a bijective function for $x\in D_f$, and its inverse $g:R_f\to D_f$, we have the identities:
$$f(g(x))=x, x\in R_f$$ and $$g(f(x))=x, x\in D_f$$
It is worth mentioning this, because this implies that the statement in your question, $\cos^2(\cos^{-1}(x))=x^2$, is only true for the domain of $\cos^{-1} x$, which of course is $x\in [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, $\cos^{-1} x$ is a real number so that $\cos(\cos^{-1} x) = x.$ Thus, $\cos^2(\cos^{-1} x) = (\cos(\cos^{-1} x))^2 = x^2.$